# Problems installing gnuplot on mac os x

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion, gnuplot

I'm getting this error after downloading the .zip file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    from __init__ import __version__
  File "/Users/me/Downloads/gnuplot-py-1.8/__init__.py", line 164, in <module>
    from gp import GnuplotOpts, GnuplotProcess, test_persist
ImportError: cannot import name GnuplotOpts
```

I have gnuplot installed on my machine, if I type gnuplot on the terminal the gnuplot terminal pops up. I'm trying to call it with python and it's saying it's not installed. This may be a path issue, but I'm just trying to make sure EVERYTHING needed is installed. (Path recommendations would be appreciated too)

Mac 10.7 Lion

Comment: try importing just Gnuplot.

Comment: Tried that too. Got `No module named Gnuplot` as an error.

Comment: try installing it by :- pip install http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/gnuplot-py/gnuplot-py-1.8.tar.gz?download

Comment: Right on. That solved my issue. Do you know why? Just an incomplete package before?

Comment: Umm , I have no idea how you installed Gnuplot . may be python package was not installed. Meanwhile I will just create another post for working command for gnuplot for other user ease

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So guys, the issue was solved by doing :

```
pip install http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/gnuplot-py/gnuplot-py-1.8.tar.gz?download
```

and importing Gnuplot.